# Django import Models

Tags: django, import, model

I am trying to import A model from the file  in the path -

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages".
```

The file witch contain the model it's called table_class_corespondance so when I import it is:from table_class_corespondance import Users.
Now in the Users class definition after I declare the field I write :

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'USERS'
    app_label = "banner_manager"
```

so that Django will know that app will make reference this table. But unfortunately this error still shows up:

```
RuntimeError: Model class table_class_corespondance.Users doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Any idea what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that this table belong to another database which.The connection to the database has the folowing structure in settings.py:

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': database_name_1,
        'USER': user_name,
        'PASSWORD': password,
        'HOST': host,
        'PORT': port,
    },

    'users': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': database_name_2,
        'USER': user_name,
        'PASSWORD':password,
        'HOST': host,
        'PORT': port,
```

} The model Users is connect to "users" database show how should db_table shoul look? Thanks for the answer